# How to build a nginx location wildcard to match /sub/test.jpg but not /test.jpg

Tags: nginx

I have a location rule in nginx which tries to catch any js, css and jpg files:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com

    location ~* \.(js|css|jpg)$ {
        root /srv/html;
    }
}
```

This works fine.  When I hit `http://example.com/test.jpg` it loads my image, so the permissions are correct.

However I want to change this so that only items under http://example.com/sub/ are matched.

So, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33299705/2052575) I changed the location to:

```
location ~* ^/sub/\.(js|css|jpg)$ {
    root /srv/html;
}
```

but this location doesn't appear to match `http://example.com/sub/test.jpg`

I also tried with:

```
location ~* ^/sub/.+\.(js|css|jpg)$ {
    root /srv/html;
}
```

which matches the location block, but looks for the file in `/srv/html/sub/` according to my error log:

```
open() "/srv/html/sub/test.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

What's the correct way to write this so that I can:

- access `http://example.com/sub/test.jpg`
- nginx retreives the file from `/srv/html/test.jpg`  (which also works for `*.jpg`, `*.css` and `*.js`)
- the rule doesn't match `http://example.com/test.jpg`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a file located at `/srv/html/test.jpg` and you want to access it using the URI `/sub/test.jpg`.

This requires the `alias` directive as the path to the file cannot be constructed by simply concatenating the document root with the URI.

For example:

```
location /sub/ {
    alias /srv/html/;
}
```

The trailing `/` on both the `location` and `alias` values is significant. Either both have a trailing `/` or neither have a trailing `/`.

---

Using the `alias` directive with a *regular expression* location block, requires you to capture the remainder of the URI and construct the path to the file in the `alias` statement.

For example:

```
location ~* ^/sub(/.+\.(js|css|jpg))$ {
    alias /srv/html$1;
}
```

The order of the *regular expression* `location` blocks is significant. The regular expressions are evaluated in order, so a more specific regular expression should be placed before a less specific regular expression.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for the `alias` directive, and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for the `location` directive.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  This works exactlly as I'd hoped.